# Browsing a file and displaying the file name using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working with this code to browse a video file:

```
def openDirectory(): 
    vidname= tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root, initialdir='/home/', title='Select your video:')
    pathlabel.config(text=os.path.basename(vidname),fg="blue")
```

But i am getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1540, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "GUI_ubuntu.py", line 15, in openDirectory
pathlabel.config(text=os.path.basename(vidname))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 114, in basename
i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Can you please help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tkFileDialog.askopenfile` returns the chosen file's file object opened in default read mode. *Not* the filename of the selected file.

Since you wanted to ask for the filename and path, you can use `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename` instead.

```
def openDirectory(): 
    vidname= tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root, initialdir='/home/', title='Select your video:')
    pathlabel.config(text=os.path.basename(vidname),fg="blue")
```